# SQL Sever Geospatial, find location of point at a distance along a linestring

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial, geo

We are investigating migrating a prototype into SQL Server (azure).

We have LineStrings that also have M values. What we would like to do is given another M value find out what its geographical location is.

To aid your visualisation, here is a real-world example:

I have a linestring that represents a flight path. Because the flight goes up and down the distance the plane has actually moved is not the same as the total length of the linestring. We have calibrated M values as a part of the linestring but need to be able to plot on it where a given event occurred. All we know about this event is its M value.

[image]

SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 0 NULL 0, 2 2 NULL 5, 1 4 NULL 9, 3 6 NULL 15)', 0);

Given something like the above, what is the lat and long of a point with an M value of 8?

This should be an equivalent postgis's [ST_LocateAlong](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_LocateAlong.html)

The M value is not a time, but a distance. It should be understood that this distance is arbitrary and does not directly relate to the length of the line and is calibrated against known points. This is due to the set being based on historic data that is in no way accurate by today's standards.

*Note I am not sure if I have Nulled the Z or M value. The extra parameter we are considering here is the M only.

Comment: I've read both the initial question and the example multiple times but I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're actually asking. Can you provide an example LineStringwith a representative query (not necessarily a SQL query) that you're trying to answer about (or with) the LineString?

Comment: I can appreciate that Ben, its an awkward question. If you are anything like me a picture will help.

Comment: So, in *your* application you're using `M` as some kind of analog for "time passed". And you want to either find a point with a given `M` value or, if the `M` value wasn't used for any point on the line, you want to apply (linear?) interpolation between the two points closest in value? Surprisingly, since that interpretation of `M` is one that you're applying, there's nothing that I'm aware of built in to compute it.

Comment: Yes Damien, linear interpolation is the only method we have come up with thus far, but it all felt a little manual. The M value is a calibrated distance but it does not always hold true to the length of the lines due to it being based on historic data that is used as a reference to locate things but is not always geographically accurate. Ive added a comment that I should have before. We currently achieve this via ST_LocateAlong in PostGis.